# A simple and safe implementation for strnstr (search for a substring in the first n characters of char array)

Tags: c++, c, strings

I'd like to suggest the following implementation:

```
// Find an instance of substr in an array of characters
// the array of characters does not have to be null terminated
// the search is limited to the first n characters in the array.
char *strnstr(char *str, const char *substr, size_t n)
{
    char *p = str, *pEnd = str+n;
    size_t substr_len = strlen(substr);

    if(0 == substr_len)
        return str; // the empty string is contained everywhere.

    pEnd -= (substr_len - 1);
    for(;p < pEnd; ++p)
    {
        if(0 == strncmp(p, substr, substr_len))
            return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The rationale for the first parameter is not to be const is that you may want to use the return value pointer to modify the array in that location.

for completeness, in C++, it's possible to add an overloaded variant that's const:

```
const char *strnstr(const char *str, const char *substr, size_t n)
{
    return strnstr((char *)str, substr, n);
}
```

Any comments?

---

As suggested, here's a test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "1234567890abcdefgh";
    size_t n = sizeof(s) - 1;

    const char *patterns[] = { "efgh", "0ab", "0b", NULL };
    const char *result = NULL;
    const char *pPattern = patterns[0];

    std::cout << "array of length " << n << " is: " << s << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; pPattern; pPattern = patterns[++i])
    {
        result = strnstr(s, pPattern, n);
        std::cout << "finding " << pPattern << " n=" << n << ": "
            << (result ? result : "(null)") << std::endl;
    }

    pPattern = patterns[0];
    result = strnstr(s, pPattern, n-1);
    std::cout << "finding " << pPattern << " n=" << n-1 << ": "
        << (result ? result : "(null)") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array of length 18 is: 1234567890abcdefgh
finding efgh n=18: efgh
finding 0ab n=18: 0abcdefgh
finding 0b n=18: (null)
finding efgh n=17: (null)
```

Comment: Your question is already good. Adding an example of usage would make it even better (even a one-liner, along with example output)

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Design:  The `str` as an *array* and searched up to `n` is inconsistent with string like functions and `strstr()`.  Rather than "the search is limited to the first n characters in the array", I'd also expect characters in `str` that follow a null character are not searched.   IMO, a design flaw.

   Following review assumes `str[i] == 0` has no special meaning.
2. Weak argument name `str`.  `str` is the address of an *array* and maybe not a *string*.  Calling a potential non-string `str` conveys the wrong idea.  Suggest `src`, etc.  When looking for sub-strings, I like `needle` and `haystack`.
3. As the C version does not change `str` contents, recommend making that `const`.  "The rationale for the first parameter is not to be const is that you may want to use the return value pointer to modify the array in that location." does not apply.  Just cast `char *` the return value.  Follow `strstr()`s tyle.

   ```
   // From C library.
         char *strstr( const char *s1, const char *s2); 

   // Expected signatures: (spaced for clarity)
   // C
         char *strnstr(const char *src, const char *substr, size_t n);
   // C++
         char *strnstr(      char *src, const char *substr, size_t n);
   const char *strnstr(const char *src, const char *substr, size_t n);
   ```
4. Using a name that is close to standard names is tricky.  C reserves name with certain prefixes, etc and so does *nix, etc.  Maybe use `CP_strnstr()` and an optional `#define strnstr CP_strnstr`.
5. Corner case: Returning `str` with `if(0 == substr_len) return str;` does not make sense when `size == 0`.  I'd expect `NULL`.
6. Underflow possible.  The length of the `needle` may be longer or shorter than the `haystack`

   ```
   // add check
   if (n + 1 < substr_len) {
     return NULL;
   }
   pEnd -= (substr_len - 1);
   ```

Minor

8. In debug mode, consider testing against `NULL`

   ```
   char *strnstr(char *str, const char *substr, size_t n) {
     assert(str || n == 0);
     assert(substr);
   ```

Comment: Point by point:
1. This was a conscious choice. The use case I had in mind was data that may arrive over the network and may include a mix of binary and ASCII data. I agree that the alternative behavior has merit as well.
2. I’ll edit the code to reflect this suggestion.
3. The way the C library is handling this silently casts away the const which is dangerous for the client code.
4. Interesting point. What does CP stand for?
5. This is a matter of personal preference.
6. This is redundant. It’s already handled by the for-loop condition.
8. Nice option.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle #3 Agree with you.  As the function does not know if `src` was originally `const char *` or `char *`.  With `strstr()`,, returning `char *` is the compromise that occurred when `const` was created.  `strstr()` pre-dates `const`.  So mimicking that style has the advantage of consistent user expectation, but is dangerous for the client code as you say.  4. CP is CplusPuzzle.  5. Returning an address outside the range imposed by `size` is problematic.  IAC, such corner case benefit by being documented.  6.When the needle is longer `pEnd` takes on an illegal value.

Comment: in 6. Even though `pEnd` takes an illegel value, it's never dereferenced, so it's fine, it's just like an int holding an "illegal number".  in 5. the address is the same address that the client code was holding anyway so it's not outside the range the way I see it.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle If the case of a large needle, the calculation of `pEnd` attempts to calculate a pointer outside the range of `&str[0]...&str[size]`.  The result does not necessary have where will  `p < pEnd` hold.  Thus the invalidity of  if if(p < pEnd)` test.

Comment: when `strlen(substr)` is larger than `size`, it's guaranteed to fail the condition for `p < pEnd` it's simple arithmetic. Remember that a pointer is just a number and the `<` operator works with pointers just like it does with numbers.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle Pointers are not integers - that is why a different name is used.  Pointer math has restrictions that integer math does not.  If code attempts pointer math with `str` and result outside `&str[0]...&str[size]`, the result is not specified.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle C11 §6.5.6 8&9 specify this restriction, else the result is undefined behavior (UB).  Should you not agree, suggest posting on SO to garner the opinion of others.

Comment: I'm sure you've done your fact-checking thoroughly :) however, this looks like over-engineering on the standards' side. I find it hard to believe that any real-world compiler would produce code that may not work in this case.

Comment: @CplusPuzzle think of code that passed a low addressed`str` as "Data:00000004".  The subtraction math done with `pEnd = (str+n) - (substr_len - 1);`  or `pEnd = (Data:00000004 + x80) - (x101 - 1)` attempts to create a pointer before the start of that page/segment of memory.  Typical pointer math is unsigned, so `pEnd` becomes `Data:FFFFFF84` due to wrap-around, now `p < pEnd` remains true for a _long_ time - or a page fault.  Rare - yes.  Harder to debug.

Comment: Pointers are not relative to their segment, they are relative to the virtual address space or absolute in the kernel space

Comment: @CplusPuzzle "Pointers are not relative to their segment," is not specified by C.  Having each object in its own segment can be/has been used in compliant C implementations.  With absolute address, the comment above still holds, just let `Data:` be 0.  `FFFFFF84` is not less than `4` - which is needed for your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

A few points here.

1. The name `strnstr` is reserved for the implementation<sup>1</sup>, so your code has undefined behavior.
2. Unless you're fairly sure that the strings you're dealing with are fairly short (or have a lot of repetition) I'd at least consider a different algorithm such as Knuth-Morris-Pratt or one of the Boyer-Moore variants.
3. Use of this should almost always be restricted to C, not C++ (in C++ you'd normally want to use `std::string`, not nul-terminated byte sequences).
4. The code can have undefined behavior. If `n` is greater than the size of buffer that `str` is pointing at, then `*pEnd = str+n;` can attempt to produce an invalid pointer. In particular, you're allowed to create a pointer to any position in the array, or you can create a pointer to a position one past the end of the array--but any more than one past the end is *not* allowed--even attempting to create that pointer (without ever attempting to dereference it) gives undefined behavior--and this isn't purely a technicality either--there have been real systems relatively recently that could throw a hardware exception for such a case (e.g., OS/2 1.x).

---

1 c draft N1570 (but the same requirements have existed since C89): "Reserved Identifiers":

> All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.

and "Future library directions":

> Function names that begin with str, mem, or wcs and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the  header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. I agree that the name should be changed if this is integrated into a project. 2. I think that such algorithms that have pre-processing and possibly memory allocations hidded inside should have their own dedicated API (so that the pre-processing can be re-used)  3. I just skimmed through the `std::string` API and I couldn't find equivalent behavior. how would you do it?

Comment: @CplusPuzzle: It's not built into `string` itself. It's essentially similar to `std::search(foo.begin(), foo.begin() + n, bar.begin(), bar.end());`. The most obvious difference is that `search` returns an iterator instead of an index (so if you want an index, subtract `foo.begin()` from the return).

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest the following based on your code. Other than style is does have two optimizations: if needle is empty no point calculating end and as I've seen elsewhere checking first char before calling strncmp seems like a good optimization.

```
char *strnstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t haystackLength) {
    size_t needleLength = strlen(needle);
    if (needleLength == 0) {
        // empty string is in any string
        return haystack;
    }

    char *end = haystack + haystackLength - (needleLength - 1);
    for (char *start = haystack; start < end; ++start) {
        // checking first char before the whole needle is an optimization
        if ((*start == *needle) && strncmp(start, needle, needleLength) == 0) {
            return start;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

As for whether haystack should be as non-const, that's how it's defined in [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strnstr&sektion=3) which I assume is what you're shooting for. It is odd that it returns non-const and the result is a pointer to or inside of haystack. Thing is, if you are searching a variable that is const, then passing it in as non-const is weird (wrong-ish). Maybe better to make both haystack and the result const. And if the caller knows it's not actually const to typecast to non-const. ... FWIW I'm thinking in C right now. Might be different considerations in the C++ world.

Answer (score 0):

The test program doesn't seem to have been reviewed yet.

A few minor problems are easily fixed:

- There's no declaration of `size_t` - it's probably better to use `std::size_t` instead.
- Prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`, as the former is strongly-typed.
- Don't use `std::endl` when there's no need to flush the stream.
- `i` seems redundant in the loop - we could simply `for (const char *pPattern = patterns[0];  pPattern;  ++pPattern)`.  Or even clearer, omit the final null pointer, and just use range-based loop: `for (const char *pPattern: patterns)`.
- There's no confirmation that the returned pointer (when not null) points within the argument string (as opposed, say, to returning the search pattern argument in some cases).
- It's lacking tests of some important cases (zero-length array and/or empty search string; inputs containing null characters).

The main problem with it, though, is that it doesn't actually *test* the function.  It exercises it with a few values, but requires the user to determine whether the behaviour was correct or not.  That's the kind of tedious activity that's best shifted to the machine, so make it return `EXIT_SUCCESS` if the tests all return the expected results, and `EXIT_FAILURE` otherwise.

Comment: fun and curious that this 7 years old post got this renewed interest. since then, I do make sure to use nullptr, however, `std::size_t` instead of `size_t` still feels weird and unnecessary

Comment: Also, calling the usage example a "test program" was clearly a misnomer